# Find an image in an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
def boardcords(img1, img2):
    img1 = asarray(img1) #what your looking for
    img2 = asarray(img2) #big
    img2y=img2.shape[0]
    img2x=img2.shape[1]
    stopy=img2y-img1.shape[0]+1
    stopx=img2x-img1.shape[1]+1
    for x1 in range(0,stopx):
        for y1 in range(0,stopy):
            x2=x1+img1.shape[1]
            y2=y1+img1.shape[0]
            pic=img2[y1:y2,x1:x2]
            test=pic==img1
            if test.all():
                return x1, y1
bx, by = boardcords(Image.open('small.png'),Image.open('test.png'))
print (bx, by)
bx2, by2 = boardcords((Image.open('small2.png')),Image.open('test.png'))
print (bx2, by2)
```

This only works sometimes for some reason. It successfully finds the image for the first test, but not the second, giving the following error

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08383055927431033826

The pictures if necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
        test=pic==img1
        if test.all():
            return x1, y1
```

`pic==img1` is of type `bool`, therefore `test` is of type `bool`, and then you try to call its `all` method, which does not exist.

Will it work if you replace it with `if test:`?

Comment: I tried that and then it doesnt work for the first one or the seconds